# Detect Electron uninstall event

Tags: node.js, electron

We have created application in Electron now we have to update a value in my database when user uninstall that application from the machine.Do we have any event  or a workaround to catch the uninstalling of electron software?

Comment: Why do you need to do detect this?

Comment: Are you using squirrel installer?